# Does OverlayFS support Quotas?

Tags: linux, quota, overlayfs

I tried mounting an overlayfs upper directory with quotas enabled (Linux system). The quota tools, however, keep telling me that quotas are not enabled on that filesystem.

This makes me wonder if quotas are supported by overlayfs at all?

Comment: Seems unlikely, since overlayfs does not actually store any data itself. Your data lives in the upper and lower filesystems; overlayfs has no way to track it.